# Outlook Gaps in Layout

Tags: html, outlook

Working with provided HTML and I'm looking to figure out why there is a gap in Outlook 07,10,13. Renders fine in other Outlook versions. The gap varies between outlook version, but a gap  nonetheless

Screenshot:
[image]

HTML Email for review:

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0062)http://nancydoyle.net/artpoint/Bengals_VIP/53_bengals-vip.html -->
<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <style type="text/css">
  <!-- .footer {
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 8pt;
   color: #666666;
   text-align: left;
  }

  table {
   font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #000000;
   text-align: left;
  }

  td {
   vertical-align: top;
  }

  body {
   background-color: #CCC;
  }

  a:link {
   color: #0018A8;
  }

  a:visited {
   color: #0018A8;
  }

  a:hover {
   color: #5B8F22;
  }

  a:active {
   color: #0018A8;
  }

  -->
 </style>

</head>

<body>
 <table width="600" style="border:2px solid #CCC" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th scope="row">
     <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" style="font-size:13px;"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <td>
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="center">
             <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
               <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFF" scope="row">
                 <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tbody>
                   <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                     <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{252633d5-413e-49d6-b98f-0d2a7a776bab}_image_top.png" alt="Bengals VIP-Sunday, Oct 11" width="600" height="324">
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <td width="90">
                     <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{ea46411e-9382-46a4-87c0-b741d0725209}_image_lt.png" width="89" height="293">
                    </td>
                    <td width="412" valign="top">
                     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

                       <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                         <p style="font-size: 17px; color: #000; font-weight: normal; line-height:1.1"><b>Please join us for a Bengals VIP Party held in <br>
          the Southeast Overlook at Paul Brown Stadium.</b>
                          <br> VIP Party includes food, beverages and Club tickets
                          <br> for you and a guest to attend the game.</p>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td height="10" colspan="3">
                         <p style="font-weight:bold; color:#0018A8; font-size:13px">
                          <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b6d6e242-ef92-4cf0-b5cf-d3081a001bfb}_spacer.gif" width="10" height="6">
                         </p>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="19%">
                         <span style="font-weight:bold; color:#0018A8; font-size:13px">11:30 am</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="74%">
                         <p style="font-weight:normal; color:#000; font-size:13px;">
                          <strong>Food and beverages will be provided in the Southeast Club Suite Overlook.</strong>
                         </p>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td height="30">
                         <span style="font-weight:bold; color:#0018A8; font-size:13px">1:00 pm</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                         <p style="font-weight:normal; color:#000; font-size:13px">
                          <strong>Kickoff.</strong> You will be escorted to your Club seats.</p>
                        </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                        <td height="32" colspan="3" align="left">
                         <span style="font-weight:bold; color:#000; font-size:12px;line-height:2.0">Spots are limited, so please RSVP on or before October 2, 2015.</span>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td height="40" colspan="3" align="center">
                         <a href="//events.53.com/BengalsVIPEvent" target="_blank">
                          <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{4c656e9b-3bd4-4596-94e5-2d2da9d83737}_VC-0315-Register_A.jpg" width="89" height="27" alt="RSVP" style="border-style: none">
                         </a>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="left">
                         <span style="font-weight:normal; color:#000; font-size:12px;line-height:1.2">If you have any questions please contact Megan Auer at 513-534-6439 or <a href="mailto:Megan.Auer@53.com">Megan.Auer@53.com</a>. Directions and tickets will be provided upon RSVP.</span>
                        </td>
                       </tr>

                     </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="98" align="right">
                     <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{e86cc6a3-148f-4cc7-9dee-1b9c22af2a6e}_image_rt.png" width="98" height="293">
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                     <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{e58b7aa4-66b1-481f-b3cc-7c5559618fb0}_image_bottom.png" alt="Fifth Third Bank" width="600" height="132">
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                  </tbody>
                 </table>

                </th>
               </tr>
              </tbody>
             </table>
             <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

             </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>
             <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b6d6e242-ef92-4cf0-b5cf-d3081a001bfb}_spacer.gif" width="31" height="15">
            </td>
            <td>
             <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b6d6e242-ef92-4cf0-b5cf-d3081a001bfb}_spacer.gif" width="20" height="15">
            </td>
            <td>
             <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b6d6e242-ef92-4cf0-b5cf-d3081a001bfb}_spacer.gif" alt="" width="31" height="15">
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top" style="font-size:8pt">
             <p class="footer">Fifth Third will never use a link in email to ask for User ID(s), password(s) or PIN(s), Social Security number(s), card or account number(s), cardholder verification value(s) (CVV2), or user defined challenge information (e.g., mother's
              maiden name, place of birth, etc.) If such a message is received, please immediately forward it to <a href="mailto:53investigation@security.53.com" class="footer">53investigation@security.53.com</a>.</p>
             <p class="footer"><b>To Unsubscribe:</b> This email was sent by Fifth Third Bank, 38 Fountain Square Plaza, Cincinnati, Ohio 45263. If you do not wish to receive future email solicitations or advertisements, please <a href="http://payments.53.com/forms/SubscriptionManagement" target="_blank">click here</a>              to manage your communications. This will allow you to select the communications you wish to receive from us.</p>
             <p class="footer">Fifth Third Bank, Member FDIC.
              <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{a29b1016-66a2-4f46-a8d9-25342ff39a97}_Equal_Housing_Lender_No_Text.gif" width="16" height="13"> Equal Housing Lender.</p>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </th>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

</body>

</html>
```

The pasted example shows the gaps more extremely than I even see in litmus tests, but not showing in Chrome when I test the HTML locally.

Answer (score 0):

FIX was to add inline CSS to the images and remove the `<tbody>`

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0062)http://nancydoyle.net/artpoint/Bengals_VIP/53_bengals-vip.html -->
<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <style type="text/css">
  <!-- .footer {
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 8pt;
   color: #666666;
   text-align: left;
  }
  
  table {
   font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #000000;
   text-align: left;
  }
  
  td {
   vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  body {
   background-color: #CCC;
  }
  
  a:link {
   color: #0018A8;
  }
  
  a:visited {
   color: #0018A8;
  }
  
  a:hover {
   color: #5B8F22;
  }
  
  a:active {
   color: #0018A8;
  }
  
  -->
 </style>

</head>

<body>
 <table width="600" style="border:2px solid #CCC" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

  <tr>
   <th scope="row">
    <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">

     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="font-size:13px;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <td>
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">

        <tr>
         <td align="center">
          <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFF" scope="row">
             <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

              <tr>
               <td colspan="3">
                <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{252633d5-413e-49d6-b98f-0d2a7a776bab}_image_top.png" alt="Bengals VIP-Sunday, Oct 11" width="600" height="324" style="width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;display:block;">
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
               <td width="90">
                <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{ea46411e-9382-46a4-87c0-b741d0725209}_image_lt.png" width="89" height="293" style="width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;display:block;">
               </td>
               <td width="412" valign="top">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

                 <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                   <p style="font-size: 17px; color: #000; font-weight: normal; line-height:1.1"><b>Please join us for a Bengals VIP Party held in <br>
          the Southeast Overlook at Paul Brown Stadium.</b>
                    <br> VIP Party includes food, beverages and Club tickets
                    <br> for you and a guest to attend the game.</p>
                  </td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                  <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td width="19%">
                   <span style="font-weight:bold; color:#0018A8; font-size:13px">11:30 am</span>
                  </td>
                  <td width="74%">
                   <p style="font-weight:normal; color:#000; font-size:13px;">
                    <strong>Food and beverages will be provided in the Southeast Club Suite Overlook.</strong>
                   </p>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td height="30">
                   <span style="font-weight:bold; color:#0018A8; font-size:13px">1:00 pm</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                   <p style="font-weight:normal; color:#000; font-size:13px">
                    <strong>Kickoff.</strong> You will be escorted to your Club seats.</p>
                  </td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                  <td height="32" colspan="3" align="left">
                   <span style="font-weight:bold; color:#000; font-size:12px;line-height:2.0">Spots are limited, so please RSVP on or before October 2, 2015.</span>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td height="40" colspan="3" align="center">
                   <a href="//events.53.com/BengalsVIPEvent" target="_blank">
                    <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{4c656e9b-3bd4-4596-94e5-2d2da9d83737}_VC-0315-Register_A.jpg" width="89" height="27" alt="RSVP" style="padding:0;margin:0;display:block;border-style:none;">
                   </a>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" align="left">
                   <span style="font-weight:normal; color:#000; font-size:12px;line-height:1.2">If you have any questions please contact Megan Auer at 513-534-6439 or <a href="mailto:Megan.Auer@53.com">Megan.Auer@53.com</a>. Directions and tickets will be provided upon RSVP.</span>
                  </td>
                 </tr>

                </table>
               </td>
               <td width="98" align="right">
                <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{e86cc6a3-148f-4cc7-9dee-1b9c22af2a6e}_image_rt.png" width="98" height="293" style="width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;display:block;">
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td colspan="3">
                <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{e58b7aa4-66b1-481f-b3cc-7c5559618fb0}_image_bottom.png" alt="Fifth Third Bank" width="600" height="132" style="width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;display:block;">
               </td>
              </tr>

             </table>

            </th>
           </tr>
          </table>
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>

       </table>
       <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

        <tr>
         <td>
          <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b6d6e242-ef92-4cf0-b5cf-d3081a001bfb}_spacer.gif" width="31" height="15">
         </td>
         <td>
          <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b6d6e242-ef92-4cf0-b5cf-d3081a001bfb}_spacer.gif" width="20" height="15">
         </td>
         <td>
          <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b6d6e242-ef92-4cf0-b5cf-d3081a001bfb}_spacer.gif" alt="" width="31" height="15">
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
         <td valign="top" style="font-size:8pt">
          <p class="footer">Fifth Third will never use a link in email to ask for User ID(s), password(s) or PIN(s), Social Security number(s), card or account number(s), cardholder verification value(s) (CVV2), or user defined challenge information (e.g., mother's maiden
           name, place of birth, etc.) If such a message is received, please immediately forward it to <a href="mailto:53investigation@security.53.com" class="footer">53investigation@security.53.com</a>.</p>
          <p class="footer"><b>To Unsubscribe:</b> This email was sent by Fifth Third Bank, 38 Fountain Square Plaza, Cincinnati, Ohio 45263. If you do not wish to receive future email solicitations or advertisements, please <a href="http://payments.53.com/forms/SubscriptionManagement"
           target="_blank">click here</a> to manage your communications. This will allow you to select the communications you wish to receive from us.</p>
          <p class="footer">Fifth Third Bank, Member FDIC.
           <img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{a29b1016-66a2-4f46-a8d9-25342ff39a97}_Equal_Housing_Lender_No_Text.gif" width="16" height="13"> Equal Housing Lender.</p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>

    </table>
   </th>
  </tr>

 </table>

</body>

</html>
```